# why my alert shows undefined in javascript

Tags: javascript, undefined

```
var database = require('../../db');
var rightponame = '1';
var rightdevname = '';
var rightpopassword = '';
var rightdevpassword = '';
database.db.once('open', function() {
  console.log('success');

  var cursor = database.db.collection('user').find({}, {
    _id: 0
  });
  cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
    if (doc != null) {
      rightponame = doc.productOwner;
      rightdevname = doc.developer;
      rightpopassword = doc.popassword;
      rightdevpassword = doc.devpassword;
      console.log(rightponame);
      console.log(rightdevname);
      console.log(rightpopassword);
      console.log(rightdevpassword);
    } else {
      console.log('o');
    }
  });


});

function login() {
  var getusername = document.getElementById("username").value;
  var getpassword = document.getElementById("password").value;

  alert(rightponame);

}
```

Finally, I get `rightponame`, `rightdevname`, `rightpopassword` and `rightdevpassword` value. But in the login function, I get undefined in the alert.
Why?

Comment: According to my codes, I think the require runs lastly, right?

Comment: Strange, but it might be the order things are executing. Maybe change the alert to a console.log to see what order everything is executing in.

Comment: If `alert` is in fact a function that you've declared or included as a dependency then you should include what it is and how you `require`d it.

Comment: Also, is your login function on the client and the db event callback on the server? because you can't mix client code with node.js. If it's separate and you are in fact using each function within their respective environment, then you should include more context with the `login` function.

Comment: Actually, I just changed **alert(rightponame)** to **console.log(rightponame)** but nothing display, so I use alert function to debug.@Sudsy

Comment: I just use alert function to check what's in rightponame.And you are right, I think I am still confuse with nodejs like that things. I need read and learn nodejs now and then see the code. :)  @Seth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript, `alert` is only available in the browser. It appears you're using node.js or the like. Try `console.log` instead, as you're doing on db open.

Then when you check the terminal window where the process is running, you should see the value of `console.log`.

Since `console.log` takes multiple values, it's helpful to prefix with something distinguishable like:

```
console.log('<<<<<<<', rightponame)
```

Comment: _"I get undefined in the alert"_. In, not instead of. The alert seems to work. `doc.productOwner` does not. OP needs to do some simple debugging.

Comment: Actually... in the example there's `document.getElementById` with a database connection handler. I think there's a lack of understanding on the OP's part with client js and server-side js.